# Linking PHP into Mootools on select

Tags: php, sql, mootools

How would I fill in the boxes of my form if I select one of the values from the dropdown menu (The dropdown is got from the DB)  Somehow in my javascript I need to connect to functions as there is to different tables involved with the form fields.

**Question**

Do I need to set the fields using $field name?

```
if(document.id('LoadExtension') && document.id('ExtensionResponse')) { // id of select box
var sel = document.id('LoadExtension'); // ser select box as var.
sel.addEvent('change', function(chg) { // add change event to select box.
    if(sel.getSelected().get('value') != '') { // on change if selected value is not empty.
        new Request.HTML({
            url : 'http://domain.co.nz/index.php?extension='+ sel.getSelected().get('value'),
            onRequest: function() {

            },
            onComplete: function(r1, r2, html, js) {
                document.id('ExtensionResponse').set('html', html);
            }
        }).send();
    }
});
```

}

The above code was set up to get from another document in the url: box but I would like to do it in one page.

Comment: btw - `sel.getSelected().get('value') != '')` - > this is wrong. getSelected on a select retruns an ARRAY in case it has multiple on. so `getSelected().get("value")` will likely return `["yourvalue", (...)]` which won't ever equal `''`. Use `selectEl.get("value")` or `selectEl.getSelected()[0].get("value")`.

Comment: here's an example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/wYtyy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for your code:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/TXHYg/4/

```
(function() {
    // anon closure for scope purposes of local vars.

    // cache selectors used repeatedly into local vars.
    var sel = document.id('LoadExtension'), resp = document.id('ExtensionResponse');

    // if they are in the dom...
    if (sel && resp) {
        // ... then attach event listener.
        sel.addEvent('change', function(event) {
            // this == sel.
            var value = this.get("value"); // cache getter.

            if (value === '') {
                return false; // do nothing if not selected/
            }

            // otherwise, it will run the request
            new Request.HTML({
                method: "get", // or post.
                data: {
                    extension: value // etc etc, can add more object properties and values
                },
                url: 'http://domain.co.nz/index.php',
                onComplete: function(r1, r2, html, js) {
                    resp.set('html', html);
                }
            }).send();
        });
    } // end if
})(); // end closure.
```

you should really look at some tutorials and examples and the documentation for Request and Request.HTML/JSON/JSONP

an example, similar to yours that works for jsfiddle through its echo testing service (slightly different data object that simulates the response)

http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/TXHYg/3/

Answer (score 0):

instead of document.id('ExtensionResponse') you can write $('ExtensionResponse')
an if you only update a content of a element you can use the update parameter from Request.HTML.

```
new Request.HTML({
        url : 'http://domain.co.nz/index.php',
        data: 'extension='+ sel.getSelected().get('value'),
        update: $('ExtensionResponse')

}).send();
```

Comment: `data:` can be an object you compose with all the fields you want sent, or it can point to a parent form element to convert to a query string.

Answer (score 0):

@medrod;
That's right about the $(), but using the latest version of mootools + making sure Jess stays library safe, document.id() is a much safer option for compatibility.

you need to build the rest of your form, and populate it, with in the result of the ajax request.
eg: http://domain.co.nz/index.php?extension=

start your first HTML form with only the drop down, then your ajax'd script will build and populate the rest of the form.

Comment: Could you do a brief example as I am not sure what goes in the extension= part